# How to solve this system of nonlinear PDE with Initial and boundary condition, with one constant variation

Tags: differential-equations

Using this code I get an error like boundary condition in consistency. how to solve this
issue and solve this nonlinear system. I am not sure about the B.C. AND I.C., in question it's
given as u=v=0 at y=0 and u= constant if y= inf. How to construct boundary conditions when the question has only that conditions?

```
Clear[u, v, ν, pde1, pde2]
pde1 = D[u[x, y], x] + D[v[x, y], y] == 0;
pde2 = u[x, y]*D[u[x, y], x] + v[x, y]*D[u[x, y], y] == ν*D[u[x, y], {y, 2}];
ic = {u[x, 0] == 0, v[x, 0] == 0};
bc = {u[0, y] == 1, v[0, y] == 0};
ν = 1;
sol = NDSolve[{pde1, pde2, ic, bc}, {u, v}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
```

Comment: 1. `NDsolve` should be `NDSolve`. 2. `v[x, 1000] = 0` should be `v[x, 1000] == 0`, remember to `Clear[v]` to remove the pollution. 3. You're setting option for `NDSolve` blindly, `MethodOfLines` is for time-dependent PDE. 4. When FEM is used, b.c. involving derivative cannot be used, see this post for more info: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/224812/1871

Comment: 5. Your simplification for Navier-stokes equation looks unusual, is it from certain literature? If so, can you add the reference?

Comment: No, because I don't think that'll help you learning _Mathematica_ efficiently. (Nasser has provided quite a bit of code sample [under your first question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/275227/1871) but your code are still full of simple mistakes, aren't you? ) Please settle down and first learn the basics of _Mathematica_. Coding blindly won't save your day. If you insist, at least first correct those simple mistakes mentioned in my previous comments and update your question, and answer the question in my last comment.

Comment: I just corrected all mistakes. The code was running but some errors will be shown. (I'm new here so within the minimum time I wish to learn lots of things, so in the hurrying race I made some mistakes so sorry for that sir) Please help me like your student.

Comment: As asked above, your system looks unusual, it's a variant of 2D static Navier-stokes equation for incompressible flow (by removing the pressure term and modifying the viscosity term). Are you sure it's correct? (Creating PDE casually can easily lead to unsolvable problem. )  Is it from certain literature? If so, can you add the reference?

Comment: This is Prandtl equation described for instance in the paper On the ill-posedness of the Prandtl equation on https://www.researchgate.net/publication/24168973_On_the_ill-posedness_of_the_Prandtl_equation . Since it has singularity at x=0, y=0 it can't be solved with Mathematica FEM due to "The minimal damping factor of 1/10000 has been reached". But we can solve it with FDM, with colocation method and with LDG as well.

Comment: May I know how the FDM work here.